# QListView only showing a single item in the view

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

I am utilizing the Model View Delegate framework used by Qt for displaying lists of objects with custom 'views' or layouts.

**Background:**

I require showing a country flag, country name, city name and an optional 'premium' rating star in a list, which can be selected by a user.

To achieve this, I use the following components:

- Model - a `QStandardItemModel`, see [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) page, which holds all the data of the `QListView` and interaction concerns, doc page
- Delegate - For drawing/displaying the data in a custom layout fashion, I use a `QStyledItemDelegate`, see [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) page.
- View - For the view, a simple `QListView` will suffice, as this is a single column list containing a collection of objects with a custom layout.

**Tutorials and Help:**

Using the following tutorial(s), 
 1. a [messageviewer](https://radekp.github.io/qtmoko/api/messageviewer.html) application showing how to implement a detailed `model-delegate-view` concept in accordance with,
 2. the basics of a simple [messaging menu](http://qt-articles.blogspot.co.za/2010/07/how-to-customize-listview-in-qt-using.html?m=1) system for Nokia smartphones, I have been able to create, with relative ease, the desired layout for my `QListView`.

**Problem:**

I am required to add `QStandardItem` items to my model, which will be added to my view. I do so, and it is confirmed by the delegate where each item is drawn by the `paint` override method.

However, during runtime, the `QListView` only displays 1 item. But I can use my up/down arrow keys to select various other items in the list.

Please see code below:

Setting up MVC(delegate):

`mainwindow.h`

```
//...
QStandardItemModel *modelServers;
ServerDelegate* serverDelegate;
//...
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
modelServers = new QStandardItemModel(0);
serverDelegate = new ServerDelegate(0);

ui->listServers->setModel(modelServers);
ui->listServers->setItemDelegate(serverDelegate);
```

and adding items (`QStandardItem`'s) to list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someList->length(); ++i) {
    Server server = someList->value(i);
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
    item->setData(server.getCountryName,         item->setData(QPixmap("", "PNG"), ServerDelegate::DataRole::CountryFlag);
    item->setData(server.getCountry(), ServerDelegate::DataRole::CountryText);
    item->setData(server.getCity(), ServerDelegate::DataRole::CityText);
    item->setData(i, ServerDelegate::ListIndex);
    //...
    modelServer->appendRow(item)
}
```

The finally the list displays the data, however the list is only populated with items, but only the first has visible text and images.

note: when scrolling down, only the top item is visible, see images below for an example.

e.g.

Initial Loaded list:

[image]

One scroll down

[image]

Selecting an item with no text/images:

[image]

**Additional Code below:**

`ServerDelegate` class handling the custom layout

`ServerDelegate.h`

```
#ifndef SERVERDELEGATE_H
#define SERVERDELEGATE_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <qglobal.h>

#include "global.h"

class ServerDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ServerDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate* parent = 0);
    virtual ~ServerDelegate();

    enum DataRole{
        CountryText = Qt::UserRole + 100,
        CityText = Qt::UserRole+101,
        CountryFlag = Qt::UserRole+102,
        SideIconFlag = Qt::UserRole+103,
        ListIndex = Qt::UserRole+105
    };

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

private:
    QFont fontCountry, fontCity;
};

#endif // SERVERDELEGATE_H
```

`ServerDelegate.cpp`

```
#include "serverdelegate.h"

ServerDelegate::ServerDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate *parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
    fontCountry = QApplication::font();
    fontCountry.setBold(true);
    fontCountry.setPointSize(QApplication::font().pointSize() + 3);

    fontCity = QApplication::font();
    fontCity.setItalic(true);
    fontCity.setPointSize(QApplication::font().pointSize() - 1);
}

ServerDelegate::~ServerDelegate(){
}

QSize ServerDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
    Q_UNUSED(index)
    QSize totalCountrySize = QPixmap("","").size();
    QSize totalSideIcon = QPixmap(":/res/images/premium", "PNG").size();

    QFontMetrics fmCountry(fontCountry);
    QFontMetrics fmCity(fontCity);

    int fontHeight = (2 * 2) + (2 * 5) + fmCountry.height() + fmCity.height();
    int iconHeight = (2 * 2) + (totalCountrySize.height() > totalSideIcon.height() ? totalCountrySize.height() : totalSideIcon.height());
    int height = (fontHeight > iconHeight) ? fontHeight : iconHeight;

    int width = option.rect.width();
    QSize size = QSize(width, height);

    return size;
}

void ServerDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

    QRect rec = option.rect;

    painter->save();
    painter->setClipRect(rec);

    QString countryText = index.data(DataRole::CountryText).toString();
    QString cityText = index.data(DataRole::CityText).toString();
    QPixmap countryFlag = QPixmap(qvariant_cast<QPixmap>(index.data(DataRole::CountryFlag)));
    QPixmap sideIcon = qvariant_cast<QPixmap>(index.data(DataRole::SideIconFlag));

    // Get a rectangle by size x, y.
    // With cooridinates [0,0]; [x,0]; [x,y]; [0,y]
    QRect topLine = option.rect,
            bottomLine = option.rect;

    // create top 'seperator' of X px's width, green in color;
    topLine.setTop(0);
    topLine.setLeft(0);
    topLine.setRight(option.rect.width());
    topLine.setBottom(2); // 1px down

    painter->setPen(QColor(116, 183, 151));
    painter->fillRect(topLine, QColor(116, 183, 151));
    painter->drawRect(topLine);

    // create bottom 'seperator' of X px's width, green in color;
    bottomLine.setTop(option.rect.height() - 2);
    bottomLine.setLeft(0);
    bottomLine.setRight(option.rect.width());
    bottomLine.setBottom(option.rect.height()); // 1px down

    painter->setPen(QColor(116, 183, 151));
    painter->fillRect(bottomLine, QColor(116, 183, 151));
    painter->drawRect(bottomLine);

    // create background rectangle
    QRect content(0, topLine.bottom(), option.rect.width(), bottomLine.top());

    painter->setPen(QColor(116, 183, 151));
    painter->fillRect(content, QColor(116, 183, 151));
    painter->drawRect(content);

    // create content rectangles from content container.

    QRect rectCountryFlag = content,
            rectSideIcon = content;

    //    create country icon rectangle
    QSize countryFlagSize = countryFlag.size();
    int cFPos = (rectCountryFlag.height() / 2) - (countryFlagSize.height() / 2) - 8;
    rectCountryFlag.setTop(cFPos);
    rectCountryFlag.setBottom(content.height() - cFPos);
    rectCountryFlag.setLeft(20 - 8);
    rectCountryFlag.setRight(20 + 16 + countryFlagSize.width());

    painter->drawPixmap(rectCountryFlag, countryFlag);

    //    create side icon rectangle
    QSize sideIconSize = sideIcon.size();
    int siPos = (rectSideIcon.height() / 2) - (sideIconSize.height() / 2) - 4;
    rectSideIcon.setTop(siPos);
    rectSideIcon.setBottom(content.height() - siPos);
    rectSideIcon.setLeft(rec.width() - (10 + 8 + sideIconSize.width()));
    rectSideIcon.setRight(rec.width() - 10);

    painter->drawPixmap(rectSideIcon, sideIcon);

    const QRect textContent(rectCountryFlag.right() + 5 + 20, content.top() + 5,
                            rectSideIcon.left() - 5, content.bottom() - 5);

    // create country text rectangle

    QRect rectCountryText = content,
            rectCityText = content;

    rectCountryText.setLeft(textContent.left());
    rectCountryText.setTop(textContent.top());
    rectCountryText.setRight(textContent.right());
    rectCountryText.setBottom(qRound(textContent.height() * 0.6) - 5);

    painter->setPen(QColor(26, 26, 26));
    painter->setFont(fontCountry);
    painter->drawText(rectCountryText, countryText);

    // create city text rectangle

    rectCityText.setLeft(textContent.left() + ( 2 * 5));
    rectCityText.setTop(rectCountryText.bottom() + 5);
    rectCityText.setRight(textContent.right());
    rectCityText.setBottom(textContent.height());

    painter->setPen(QColor(77, 77, 77));
    painter->setFont(fontCity);
    painter->drawText(rectCityText, cityText);

    // restore painter
    painter->restore();
}
```

Comment: Stacktrace? This question doesn't produce an error I am querying, it is rather the behaviour I am querying, and as to why only one item's text/images are visible while there are clearly multiple items 'stored' in the listview.

Comment: Going to your question, I am trying to reproduce this question, but there are fields that I do not know like AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Width, so there are many things. You could improve the example code by showing a [mcve]. In a slight glance I can say that your code looks good, but by not testing it I can not give you an objective opinion.

Comment: change all Global::* to a default value, for example Global::getCountryFlagFromCache, since for example this returns the recommended size that maybe is causing the error.

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you for your advice, please see updated post. This contains new values which can be used for your testing purposes

Comment: If I have seen that you have changed but you need to change Global::getCountryFlagFromCache. :P

Comment: I missed that one. `Global::getCountryFlagFromCache(QString)` simply returns a QPixmap of the country's flag

Comment: to do the test quickly, you could share your code through github.

Comment: I had such problem before with custom delegates. The problem was the offset of each item. In the paint method of the delegate I was drawing everything at origin of (0, 0), which caused the effect you described. In your paint method I see `QRect topLine = option.rect` and then `topLine.setTop(0);`. Furthermore there is `QRect content(0, topLine.bottom(), option.rect.width(), bottomLine.top());`. In my opinion it is the same mistake? Use the provided origin of the `option.rect` (without modifying it) and it should be fine.

Comment: @scopchanov thanks for your response. I have been bruteforcing my way through this and think I may be reaching a smilar conclusion. Though my tests so far, including switching to `QItemDelegate`, is that displaying only text or even a solid black rectangle produces the desires result, but when I introduce my custom paint method, it starts falling to pieces. The prupose of the topLine.setTop(0) is seen in the attached images to create a 'seperator' line. How would you suggest I change this `top` value to assimulate a sepeartor between items?

Comment: Please take a look at [that](https://github.com/scopchanov/CustomList/tree/master/app/src).

Comment: @scopchanov thank you very much, I shall study it and post my solution. Yours is impressive to say the least.

Comment: Thank you for this very positive feedback! Please feel free to use the code as it is or modify it for your own purposes. If you don't mind I will add the explaination about the origins as an answer to help anyone who might stumble upon this problem in the future.

Comment: @scopchanov please do as I had a difficult time getting to a solid example of listview-model-delegate framework, which may be evident in my post ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161071/discussion-between-scopchanov-and-kgcybex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I post my answer, a big shoutout to [scopchanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5366641/scopchanov) for his assistance and example provided, also hinting to the fact that an offset occurs on each call to the `paint`, something that I was blissfully unaware of.

**Problem Explained:**

The offset values provided by `option.rect` is the same `QSize` which is returned by the `sizeHint` method. In my case, my concern was with the `y offset` which had a value of `56`.

**My Understanding**

Using the concept of the iterative offset value, I modified my code (which had previously the desired output), where I assumed that the `paint` method was drawn from an origin of `[0,0]`, where infact I had to account for the offset aswel, i.e. I was not provided with a *container* which was placed at the next `QListView` item's location, instead I was given the location of the next `QListView`'s item start point, and am required to build the item from there.

**The solution:**

In my case, I had the desired item layout, but items were drawn ontop of each other, due to the [0,0] origin, causing the `single item` effect. After changing a few values, and building a *dependency hierachy* of sorts, I was presented with a list of items having the desired layout.

**The Code**

Updated ServerDelegate.cpp

```
#include "serverdelegate.h"

ServerDelegate::ServerDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate *parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
    fontCountry = QApplication::font();
    fontCountry.setBold(true);
    fontCountry.setPointSize(QApplication::font().pointSize() + 3);

    fontCity = QApplication::font();
    fontCity.setItalic(true);
    fontCity.setPointSize(QApplication::font().pointSize() - 1);
}

ServerDelegate::~ServerDelegate(){
}

QSize ServerDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
    Q_UNUSED(index)
    QSize totalCountrySize = Global::getCountryFlagFromCache(index.data(DataRole::CountryText).toString()).size();
    QSize totalSideIcon = QPixmap(":/res/images/premium", "PNG").size();

    QFontMetrics fmCountry(fontCountry);
    QFontMetrics fmCity(fontCity);

    int fontHeight = (2 * AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Width) + (2 * AppGlobal::Style_List_Text_Item_Margin) + fmCountry.height() + fmCity.height();
    int iconHeight = (2 * AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Width) + (totalCountrySize.height() > totalSideIcon.height() ? totalCountrySize.height() : totalSideIcon.height());
    int height = (fontHeight > iconHeight) ? fontHeight : iconHeight;

    int width = option.rect.width();
    QSize size = QSize(width, height);

    return size;
}

void ServerDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

    QFontMetrics fmCountry(fontCountry);
    QFontMetrics fmCity(fontCity);

    QRect rec = option.rect;

    painter->save();
    painter->setClipRect(rec);

    QString countryText = index.data(DataRole::CountryText).toString();
    QString cityText = index.data(DataRole::CityText).toString();
    QPixmap countryFlag = QPixmap(qvariant_cast<QPixmap>(index.data(DataRole::CountryFlag)));
    QPixmap sideIcon = qvariant_cast<QPixmap>(index.data(DataRole::SideIconFlag));

    // Get a rectangle by size x, y.
    // With cooridinates [0,0]; [x,0]; [x,y]; [0,y]
    QRect topLine = option.rect,
            bottomLine = option.rect;

    // create top 'seperator' of X px's width, green in color;
    topLine.setTop(rec.top());
    topLine.setLeft(rec.left());
    topLine.setRight(rec.right());
    topLine.setBottom(rec.top() + AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Width); // 1px down

    painter->setPen(AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Color);
    painter->fillRect(topLine, AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Color);
    painter->drawRect(topLine);

    // create bottom 'seperator' of X px's width, green in color;
    bottomLine.setTop(rec.bottom() - AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Width);
    bottomLine.setLeft(rec.left());
    bottomLine.setRight(rec.right());
    bottomLine.setBottom(rec.bottom()); // 1px down

    painter->setPen(AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Color);
    painter->fillRect(bottomLine, AppGlobal::Style_List_Seperator_Color);
    painter->drawRect(bottomLine);

    // create background rectangle
    QRect content(rec.left(), topLine.bottom(), (rec.right() - rec.left()), (bottomLine.top() - topLine.bottom()));

    painter->setPen(AppGlobal::Style_List_Background_Color);
    painter->fillRect(content, ((option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver) ? AppGlobal::Style_List_Hover_Color : AppGlobal::Style_List_Background_Color ));
    painter->drawRect(content);

    // create content rectangles from content container.

    QRect rectCountryFlag = content,
            rectSideIcon = content;

    //    create country icon rectangle
    QSize countryFlagSize = countryFlag.size();
    int cFPos = ((rectCountryFlag.bottom() - rectCountryFlag.top()) / 2) - (countryFlagSize.height() / 2) - 8;
    rectCountryFlag.setTop(rectCountryFlag.top() + cFPos);
    rectCountryFlag.setBottom(content.bottom() - cFPos);
    rectCountryFlag.setLeft(AppGlobal::Style_List_Left_Item_Margin - 8);
    rectCountryFlag.setRight(AppGlobal::Style_List_Left_Item_Margin + 16 + countryFlagSize.width());

    painter->drawPixmap(rectCountryFlag, countryFlag);

    //    create side icon rectangle
    QSize sideIconSize = sideIcon.size();
    int siPos = ((rectSideIcon.bottom() - rectSideIcon.top()) / 2) - (sideIconSize.height() / 2) - 4;
    rectSideIcon.setTop(rectSideIcon.top() + siPos);
    rectSideIcon.setBottom(content.bottom() - siPos);
    rectSideIcon.setLeft(rec.width() - (AppGlobal::Style_List_Right_Item_Margin + 8 + sideIconSize.width()));
    rectSideIcon.setRight(rec.width() - AppGlobal::Style_List_Right_Item_Margin);

    painter->drawPixmap(rectSideIcon, sideIcon);

    int textContentLeft = rectCountryFlag.right() + AppGlobal::Style_List_Text_Item_Margin + AppGlobal::Style_List_Left_Item_Margin,
            textContentTop = content.top() + AppGlobal::Style_List_Text_Item_Margin;

    const QRect textContent( textContentLeft , textContentTop,
                            (rectSideIcon.left() - AppGlobal::Style_List_Text_Item_Margin) - textContentLeft, (content.bottom() - AppGlobal::Style_List_Text_Item_Margin) - textContentTop);

    // create country text rectangle

    QRect rectCountryText = content,
            rectCityText = content;

    rectCountryText.setLeft(textContent.left());
    rectCountryText.setTop(textContent.top());
    rectCountryText.setRight(textContent.right());
    rectCountryText.setBottom(textContent.top() + fmCountry.height());

    painter->setPen(AppGlobal::Style_Heading_Color);
    painter->setFont(fontCountry);
    painter->drawText(rectCountryText, countryText);

    // create city text rectangle

    rectCityText.setLeft(textContent.left() + ( 2 * AppGlobal::Style_List_Text_Item_Margin));
    rectCityText.setTop(rectCountryText.bottom());
    rectCityText.setRight(textContent.right());
    rectCityText.setBottom(textContent.bottom() + fmCity.height());

    painter->setPen(AppGlobal::Style_SubText_Color);
    painter->setFont(fontCity);
    painter->drawText(rectCityText, cityText);

    // restore painter
    painter->restore();
}
```

Comment: If you like the example, probably you will find [this example](https://github.com/scopchanov/examples) of using [that library](https://github.com/scopchanov/flat-gui) usefull too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is caused by a mistake in the reimplementation of the `paint` method in the custom [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html). You assume (0, 0) as the origin and paint everything relative to that point. However, each item has a vertical offset, which you have to take into account by using the geometry of [QStyleOption::rect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoption.html#rect-var) instead.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-CustomList) of a fancy delegate with custom drawings and animations to help you further.

Comment: a small update, for what it is worth. You were 100% correct with the offset. I was not aware of this, that each call to paint added in my case `yOffset += 56px`, and by finding the *middle* of the newly offset block quite rapidly made my elements disappear, resulting in 1 item appearing. I thank you, good sir!